# Is there an possibility to save a dynamic pdf as static but still have interactive fields within the document?

Tags: pdf, adobe, docusignapi, aem, dynamicpdf

I have a dynamic pdf which I want to use for DocuSign and thus needs to be static. I cannot simply make use of the print as pdf function as I still want to use the interactive fields within the pdf.

I Tried to use Adobe AEM Forms Designer to save the document as static. But solely the first page of the form is saved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your concern, I would like to share the following information, you can  learn about PDF form field transformation. It enables you to transform PDF form fields automatically into DocuSign tabs, carrying over all of their existing values. The locations of the created tabs will match the locations of the fields from which they were generated.

To transform PDF form fields into DocuSign tabs, you need to set the transformPdfFields property on the documents whose fields you want to transform.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/pdf-transform/

https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-pdf-form-field-transformation

Best Regards,

Eric | DocuSign